# Пиноккио и Буратино

Tags: литература

Возможно, по этому вопросу написано много статей, но спрошу тут.
А именно: для чего, собственно, Толстому понадобилось переписывать сказку К. Коллоди? Чем Пиноккио не угодил советской идеологии и чем "Буратино" лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вы читали, простите, Пиноккио? Хотя бы в неадаптированном переводе?
Почитайте. Многие вопросы отпадут. Националист с клерикальным душком Коллоди - это ж вам не коммунист Родари...

Впрочем, при всей моей нелюбви к совковой пропаганде, Буратино: а) лучше б) вполне независимая книга. Это даже не пересказ. Это совсем другая история, где действуют некоторые герои Коллоди. Вернее - немного на них похожие. 
Ну и в). А "Доктор Айболит", в девичестве "Доктор Дулитл"? "Волшебник Изумрудного города" aka "Страны Оз"? 
Будете смеяться, единственный вполне оригинальный известный детский герой русской российской-советской эпохи - Незнайка. Все остальные либо не моложе Ивана Грозного, либо списаны.

Comment: А как же чебурашка? Есть ещё Электроник, Мойдодыр, дядя Стёпа, Хрюша и др. Совсем-то прибедняться не стоит.

Comment: Вообще-то я про более раннюю эпоху. То, что я лично читал в детстве.
А если по сути... Чебурашка - это мультик. Книгу мало кто читал. 
Дядя Стёпа - ну никак не претедует на роль сказочного героя. "Стёпа и Хрюша" - эти-то что делают в литературном кружке?  

Электроник... ну пожалуй. Хотя его тоже знают в основном по фильму. Но тогда уж и Алису добавьте. Которая, конечно, сильно напоминает свою английскую тезку, но вспоминать - так всех.

Comment: Так и Буратино, ни говоря уж о Пиноккио мало кто читал, а знают по фильму или мультику. Если ту эпоху, то тогда в сказку жизнь превращали, потому и герои соответствующие, реалистичные. Мальчиш Кибальчиш, 3 толстяка, да тех же героев Носова, особо сказочными не назовёшь.

Comment: Старик Хоттабыч тоже переписанный персонаж... А вот Тимур и его коммандос - настоящая отечественная сказка! И герои там замечательные, что ни говори.

Comment: >настоящая отечественная сказка!   
  
Ключевое слово "сказка"?  Есть в нем, конечно, что-то мифологическое, но по отзывам старшего поколения (тех, кому сейчас за восемдесят), в этой сказке есть доля сказки. Только доля.

А вообще слышал я что подобные рассказы про благородных бойскаутов были популярны в Америке в начале века (под коим я разумею первые лет двадцать пять - тридцать). Вот только убедительных источников никто не приводил.

Comment: >Так и Буратино, ... мало кто читал?  
  
Ну знаете... Я фильм помню весьма смутно. А книжку, в *три* (sic!) года читаную...

>Мальчиш Кибальчиш, 3 толстяка, да тех же героев Носова, особо сказочными не назовёшь.  

Я и не называю. Но Носов - это еще и Незнайка. Он-то вполне себе сказочен. Имхо.

Comment: Коротышки в Незнайке - это персонажи скорей фантастические, чем сказочные. Модель построенного коммунизма. И загнивающего капитализма в "лунной" части. А гротескная условность вполне типических персонажей  это признак как раз фантастики, а не сказки.  
Ну, а по поводу Буратино... В детстве герои Успенского (Матроскина ещё забыли) мне были посимпатичней, хотя прочитано это было примерно в одном возрасте. Так что это целиком дело вкуса.

Comment: Кстати, что до Электроника, то, на мой взгляд, книга Велтистова слабее фильма. По крайней мере, мне она понравилась куда меньше. И, честно говоря, впервые слышу, что Доктор Айболит списан с доктора Дулиттла. По-моему, идея сама по себе достаточно простая, чтобы прийти в голову независимо разным людям.  
И почему "Буратино" мало кто читал? У меня такая чудесная книга была в детстве!

Comment: >Так и Буратино, ни говоря уж о Пиноккио мало кто читал

Я знаю достаточно тех, кто читал С УДОВОЛЬСТВИЕМ в детстве книгу "Буратино". И современных детей в т.ч. И я читал "Буратино" именно с удовольствием. А вот "Пиноккио" я в детстве хоть и осилил, но с трудом. Показалось занудным и растянутым. Стимулом дочитать (а не бросить), было, помню, то, что *это же та самая книга по которой написан "Буратино"!!* :-) Она же наверное ещё лучше? Ан нет!

Comment: Параллели между Буратино и Тимуром. Их неожиданно много. Фильмы были поставлены дважды и одновременно - в самом конце 30-х и в середине 70-х. Противоборствуют две группы, жестоко и беспощадно. Карабас-Квакин с Дуремаром-Фигурой ищут сокровища/грабят сады, им помогают мелкие **прихвостни**; Буратино-Тимур с Мальвиной-Женей и верными друзьями мечтают играть в своем театре/по своим правилам. Карабаса приматывает бородой к сосне, Квакину одевают на голову шутовской колпак, все заканчивается всеобщим весельем! В стране дураков???

Comment: Я вот все про Чебурашку думаю. А есть вообще в мировой литературе сказки (не путать с детским фэнтези типа Незнайки или муммитроллей), действуют не люди, не куклы, не предметы там или овощи, а такие вот подарки из Африки, родства не помнящие? 

ЗЫ Ращницу между сказками и "детским фэтези" я вижу в том, что герои первыъ действуют во вполне человечьем мире. А не в собственном.